# Can't add a query to tableadapter

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to add the below query to tableadapter :

```
SELECT Pub, Desk, SubDeadline, MAX(SupPages) AS SupPages,  
    MIN(LastPlateTime) AS FirstPlate, MAX(LastPlateTime) AS LastPlate, 
    COUNT(Form) AS FormCount,
    IIF(SubDeadline>=MAX(LastPlateTime),'Yes','No') AS [OnTime]
FROM     ITRecords
WHERE  (Pub = #11/15/2018#) AND (Supplements = 'ITH')
GROUP BY Pub, Desk, SubDeadline
```

when i run the "Execute Query" it gives these errors:

[image]

i think this line which generate the error :

```
IIF(SubDeadline>=MAX(LastPlateTime),'Yes','No') AS [OnTime]
```

any idea how to fix it, i can't add it to the table.
i am using vb.net 2015 with access database
best

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it would be required but my first thought would be to leave spaces around the operator.  That's just common sense because it makes the code more readable and more readable is always better.

Comment: i've replace it with : IIF(  DeadLine   >=   LastPlate, ' Yes '  ,  ' No '  ) but giving this : "Error in list of function arguments: '>' not recognized.
Unable to parse query text."

Comment: Can you paste the query into Access and see if it works there.

Comment: Yes I’ve tried it on Access and it worked .. so i saved it as a view and take it as a table on vb. Thanks